# Make a backward string its own string?

Tags: c++

I am brand new to programming so none of this may be right.  I was just messing around trying to get the effect that I (finally) achieved.  More for practice than anything else, but I wondered if there was another way to do it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str1="Don't even think about it!";
    string str2;
    string str3;
    string str4 = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++){
        str2 = str1.substr (0, str1.length()-i);
        cout << str2 << str4;

        for (int x = str2.length() - 1; x >= 0; x--){
                str3 = str1[x];
                cout << str3;
        }

        str4 = str4 + "  ";
        cout << "\n";
    }
    getch();
    main();
    return 0;
    }
```

The question I have is this:  Is there a way to make the str3, after it is backwards, its own string that I could then justify right instead of adding spaces with str4?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's own string" ? Also, you should never call the main function.

Comment: This will end in a StackOverflow...

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I wouldn't call main at the end of main it results in a recursive loop

Comment: @Borgleader, More cannot than should not.

Comment: @chris well it compiles under Visual studio, so should not it is.

Comment: @KillianDS Depends on your definition of cannot I guess, my definition is if the compiler disallows it then you cannot. Also, (this is not the case here) but you could technically have a conditional return before the call to main that would avoid infinite recursion even when calling main. So again, should not.

Comment: @ David H  I was just trying to make a mirror image of the original string that loses a character with every loop.

Comment: @Borgleader, Fine, cannot according to the standard. We all know how much VS loves strictly adhering to that, though 2013 is getting a bit better.

Comment: It was more about trying to make a string out of the result of the nested "for" loop that I could set the width for and then justify right.  Instead it is just collection of characters.  Right now setting the width just makes every character take up the width.  Ugh, I'm trying to be clear.  Sorry.  I will learn the right way to ask things.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get a reversed string, just pass the reverse-iterators to the constructor of a new string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() {
    std::string s = "this is a test";
    std::string s_reversed(s.rbegin(), s.rend());
    std::cout << s << "\n" << s_reversed << "\n";
}
```

The output is:

```
$ g++ test.cc && ./a.out
this is a test
tset a si siht
```

Applied to your problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() {
    std::string s = "this is a test";
    for (auto i = s.length(); i > 0; i--) {
        std::cout << s;
        std::cout << std::string(s.rbegin(), s.rend());
        std::cout << '\n';
        s[i-1] = ' ';
    }
}
```

Note that there also is an algorithm in the standard library to reverse a container, e.g., a string: `std::reverse()`.

For reference:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rbegin
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rend
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse

Comment: Ah ha!  I didn't know that s.rbegin() and s.rend() existed.  That helps further my knowledge.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:
replacing letters for whitespace and then reversing the string.
Concat the modified string with the reverse of it and print it.

```
std::string reverse(std::string str)
{
    std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    std::string str = "Don't even think about it!";

    size_t N = str.length();
    for (size_t i = 1; i < N; i++)
    {   
        std::cout << str << reverse(str) << std::endl;
        str.replace(N-i,1, " ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Enigma.  That looks like it should work.  I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

First I would rename the variables so it is more clear what you are trying to achieve. Believe me, in two months you will not have a clue what this code actually does. Suggestion:

str1 -> baseString

str2 -> forwardsClippedString

str3 -> backwardsClippedString

str4 -> gapString

Maybe these names are not even good but I think they are better than str1, ..., str4.

Then I would make a separate method of the inner loop. After that make a separate method of the outer for loop - yes, main() shouldn't be complicated at all.

Finally instead of recursively calling main I suggest to do a while-loop. An infinite one if you please (but it would be nice if one key quits the loop then).

Comment: And thank you Tobi.  Good suggestions.  I'll take that into account when naming variables.  I will figure this stuff out.